# Has the Square refund API stopped working?

Tags: square

Has the refund **stopped working** for transactions created using the Point of Sale API (iOS)?

We've been using the [Square Connect V2 API](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2/2019-02-13) for a while now for refunds, we haven't migrated yet to the [Payments API](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api).

We process online payments through the [Payment Form](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/paymentform) and in-person payments using the [POS SDK (iOS)](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/point-of-sale) and have been refunding all the transactions without a problem using the, now deprecated, [create-refund](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/transactions-api/create-refund) endpoint.

But now all of the sudden the refund for in-person transactions started replying with the error `Unknown payment with id XXXXXXXXXXX` even when issuing the refund through the new Payments API.

When I call the [list payments](https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/payments-api/list-payments) method, all the online transactions have an equivalent payment and the refund works, but for in-person transactions, there is no equivalent payment record.

Example request: **Using deprecated Transactions API**

```
curl https://connect.squareup.com/v2/locations/LOCATION_ID/transactions/TRANSACTION_ID/refund \
-x POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-d '{"amount_money":{"currency":"USD","amount":100},"reason":"requested_by_customer","tender_id":"XXXXXXXXXXX","idempotency_key":"some-idempotency”}'
```

Response when refunding an online transaction:

```
{"refund":{"id":"ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY","location_id":"LOCATION_ID","transaction_id":"TRANSACTION_ID","tender_id":"XXXXXXXXXXX","created_at":"2020-01-28T19:20:27.672Z","reason":"requested_by_customer","amount_money":{"amount":100,"currency":"USD"},"status":"PENDING"}}
```

Response when refunding an in-person transaction:

```
{"errors":[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"BAD_REQUEST","detail":"Unknown payment with id XXXXXXXXXXX"}]}
```

Example request: **Using Payments API**

```
curl https://connect.squareup.com/v2/refunds \
-x POST \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-d '{"amount_money":{"currency":"USD","amount":100},"reason":"requested_by_customer","payment_id":"XXXXXXXXXXX","idempotency_key":"some-idempotency"}'
```

Response when refunding an online transaction:

```
{"refund": {"id": "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ_YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY","status": "PENDING","amount_money": {"amount": 100,"currency": "USD"},"payment_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX","order_id": "ORDER_ID","created_at": "2020-01-28T19:32:21.780Z","updated_at": "2020-01-28T19:32:21.970Z","location_id": "LOCATION_ID","reason": "requested_by_customer"}}
```

Response when refunding an in-person transaction:

```
{"errors": [{"code": "BAD_REQUEST","detail": "Unknown payment with id XXXXXXXXXXX","category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR"}]}
```

Comment: Hey Jose, there was a temporary issue on Square's side that was preventing refunds for cash payments (only via the APIs). This should be resolved...can you please try again and let me know if that's not the case?

Comment: Hi sjosey, just tried and it didn´t work with the same error.

Comment: It seems to be working when using the Transactions API but it's still failing with the Payments API

Comment: Hey sorry for the confusion. Cash transactions cannot be refunded via the Payments API. At this time, the Payments API does not know about cash payments, so you'll need to continue using Transactions API if you choose to refund cash payments.

Comment: Thank you sjosey for that clarification, I've implemented the control to issue the refund through the correct API. But now in some weird cases, I'm receiving the error `REFUND_AMOUNT_INVALID` indicating the transaction has already been refunded even when no refunds have been issued (A second transaction with the exact values can be refunded with no problem)

Comment: Hi Jose, would you be able to reach out to Square's API support? We'll need more information to dig into this (like your Square app id). Please fill out the form here if you continue having this problem, and reference this StackOverflow issue: https://squareup.com/help/us/en/contact?panel=BF53A9C8EF68

Comment: Yes, we are already in contact with support for that specific case (but it seems limited to the sandbox environment), we've just notice the same error (`Unknown payment with id ...`) is appearing for check or any other payment type refund via the transactions API. It's only working for cash payments.